# Use fosuser registration form on multiple urls

Tags: forms, symfony, routes, registration, fosuserbundle

I want to use the fosuser registration form on different urls for different languages. Like for example /en/register and /de/registrierung.

```
# app/config/routing.yml

fos_user_register_de:
    pattern: /de/registrierung
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:register }
    methods: [GET,POST]
    requirements:
        _locale: de

fos_user_register_en:
    pattern: /en/registration
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Registration:register }
    methods: [GET,POST]
    requirements:
        _locale: en
```

On submit of the form I get an error because the route name is not "fos_user_registration_register". Same thing on the confirmation.

Is there a way to do this without using a bundle like [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle)?

Comment: Why two routes? Can be combined as one. And can you copy the whole error message into the question? 'cause the RegistrationController should not check how the route is named.

Comment: How would I do that? How would I combine those two urls in one pattern?

Comment: `pattern: /{_locale}/registration` normally, but I didn't saw the translation on registration. But there's also a solution, the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this problem is, that there is none.

The only way to solve it is, to implement an own form and create a user manually.

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem is, that the bundle redirects to a specific route id and I would need to have two of those. @Pazi already mentioned the Bundle.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. If you care to elaborate I might be able to help you or maybe realize you are right and there is no solution. As Pazi mention you can combine those tow urls with the JMSI18nRoutingBundle. What do you mean by it redirects to a specific route? When you submit or when you try to access the form?

Comment: There are two routes for the registration. One for the register form and one for the success page. I can change the route names and paths for the start page, but not for the successpage, as it has to be "fos_user_registration_confirm", because the bundle redirects to that route ($url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');". As long as I can't choose the target route it should redirect to, it doesn't matter that I can "translate" the route. JMSI18nRoutingBundle might be a great bundle for a lot of things, but it doesn't help here.

Comment: With JMSI18nRoutingBundle you can use one route and one template with text displayed in the current locale. You can just override the template loaded by the route fos_user_registration_confirmed to customize it to your needs and add your translations. This is assuming all users are of the same type(stored in the same database table).
Another way is to just override the action in the registration controller that does the confirmation and decide where to redirect.
You mention PUGXMultiUserBundle. This bundle is to use the FOSUserbundle when you need more than one user type and roles isn't enough